# Simplest way of sending a large file between two servers with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I'm building two applications that interact with each other. One is a web service running on either a Windows or Unix machine that has methods available to perform various actions on files. The other is a web server that provides an interface for users to interact with the service. One requirement is the ability to upload AND download files >100MB (but might as well be any size). I've been trying to make it work by putting the file's bytes into a SOAP request like I have with all the other services but I keep getting OutOfMemory errors with larger files. I've tried using Axiom and JAXB with MTOM enabled to try and stream the bytes but going by the Spring MTOM sample ([particularly this part](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-ws/blob/master/samples/mtom/client/spring-ws/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/samples/mtom/client/sws/AxiomMtomClient.java)), it seems like you have to really get into some nasty code to get it working correctly. Is there a more obvious and simple choice for sending a large file between two servers with Spring?

As a side-question, is there an eaiser way of sending a file upload request object created with JAXB to where you don't have to write as much code as in the MTOM sample above? Something as simple as:

```
StoreFileRequest request = new StoreFileRequest();
request.setDestination(destination);
request.setFileData(dataHandler);
getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request)
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: For starters, setup http compression(GZIP) on both servers and increase the memory available to both JVMs

Answer (score 0):

Use apache fileupload even Spring websites links to it

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fup.cgi">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
  Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

Note: each browser has it's own max size:take a look at the first link below.

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: I can't send the file to the service directly, it has to be sent to the web server first (which it already does) and then it gets passed to the service. Didn't know about the file limits though, thanks.